# Python conflict between 2 libraries: requests.get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, home-assistant

I'm using Home Assistant and I'm trying to fix this GitHub issue: https://github.com/home-assistant/core/issues/75739

In short, what happens is that 2 plugins (`toshiba-ac` and `solaredge`) conflict with each other. The error we get is `requests.get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. After doing some digging, the `get` that is causing a problem is being done here: https://github.com/bertouttier/solaredge/blob/master/solaredge/solaredge.py (line 55 and so on).

Looking at the relevant dependencies, I see:

- [solaredge](https://github.com/bertouttier/solaredge) -> `requests` (no version mentioned, so latest?)
- [home-assistant-toshiba-ac](https://github.com/h4de5/home-assistant-toshiba_ac) -> [toshiba-ac](https://github.com/KaSroka/Toshiba-AC-control) ->
  [azure-iot-device==2.9.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python) -> `requests>=2.20.0,<3.0.0"`

`requests`'s latest version is 2.28.2 ([see here](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)).

Once I remove `home-assistant-toshiba-ac`, `solaredge` works fine. So it seems like a conflict, but following the dependency tree, I don't understand how that's possible. To me, it seems both are using the latest version of `requests`.

I have limited Python knowledge but I'd happy to learn and do the work on this. Can someone please point me in the right direction to help solve this issue? Any tips would be welcome!

Thanks!